# Show that the following sequence, if $n>12, $ $|a_n-L|<\frac{1}{n}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Sequence: $a_n=\frac{5n}{4n-3}$

I know that  $|a_n-L|=\frac{15}{4(4n-3)}$, but where do I go from here? I've alternatively tried using the triangle inequality, but it doesn't seem to be to much avail.
Any ideas?

Also, how would I go about proving from first principles that the sequence converges to $\frac{5}{4}$? I know that I need to show that, given any $\epsilon>0$, $|a_n-\frac{5}{4}|<\epsilon$; the algebra's not the problem. It's the argument, especially towards the end.

Comment: If $n > 12$, then $4(4n-3) = 16n - 12 > 15n$.

Comment: What value are you using for $L$? Is it $\frac54$? How do you know the inequality about $|a_n-L|$?

Comment: Yes- $L=\frac{5}{4}$ (via some informal reasoning). That inequality is what I'm trying to prove.

Comment: Levon's comment should do it. Do you see how?

Comment: Yep- very succinct and to-the-point. Thanks, @Levon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement that $|a_n - L| < 1/n$ is not **universally true**. What you have to show is that this true for all $n>N_o$ for some $N_o$.

To show that, you already have
$$
|a_n - 5/4| = \frac{15}{4(4n-3)} \tag1
$$
You want to show that the right hand side is less than $1/n$.

Now
$$
\frac 1 n - \frac{15}{4(4n-3)} = {{n-12}\over{4\,n\,\left(4\,n-3\right)}}
$$
and the difference is greater than zero for $n>12$.

Since the right hand side of (1) approaches $15/16$ from below, any $k > 15/16$ can be use to bound the right hand side of (1) as $k/n$. This is often useful when you do not know how to find the bound. For example if you pick $k=31/32$ (just for variety)
$$\left|{{31}\over{32\,n}}-{{15}\over{4\,\left(4\,n-3\right)}}\right|={{4\,n-93
 }\over{32\,n\,\left(4\,n-3\right)}}$$
and the difference is greater than zero for $n>93/4$. Hence for $n>93/4$
$$
|a_n - 5/4| = {{31}\over{32\,n}} 
$$